# KOMA script: How to reduce vertical space below caption

Tags: spacing, floats, captions, koma-script

The vertical space below figure caption is large how to reduce it.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample chapter}

\section{Sample section}

%
%
Some text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text.

\begin{figure}[htb!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{frog.jpg}
\caption{A test caption without label for a figure}
\end{figure}

%
Some text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text.


\end{document}
```

[image]

> Q: Why i get typearea warning? what does it mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Updated `\belowcaptionskip` (default is `0pt`) to a negative value:

[image]

On the left is the default; on the right is `\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-\baselineskip}`.

Answer (score 8):

You can load the `caption` package and use this setup (adjust `-5pt` to your needs):

```
\captionsetup[figure]{belowskip=-5pt}
```

[image]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{scrbook}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{belowskip=-5pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample chapter}

\section{Sample section}

%
%
Some text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text.

\begin{figure}[htb!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{frog.jpg}
\caption{A test caption without label for a figure}
\end{figure}

%
Some text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text.


\end{document}
```